# this.props.history.replace in react-router-dom v6

Tags: reactjs

I've previously used react-router-dom v4.2.2. There I used `this.props.history.replace('/path', state)` to redirect the page to another page. (Hence it will not store in the address history). Now I have to use react-router-dom v6. but receive the following error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'replace')
I tried adding `this.props.navigate('/path', {state})` but not working.
plesase help me!
file connect.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import User from './user';
import request from './request';
import { connect as rdConnect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { Redirect, Switch, Route, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';


export class ContextWrap extends Component {
    getChildContext() {
        return {
            user: new User(this.props.account, this.redirect),
            request: request,
            options: this.props.options,
            redirect: this.redirect,
            locale: this.props.account.user ? this.props.account.user.metas.locale : null,
        };
    }

    redirect = (to, push) => {
        if (typeof to == 'string') {
            to = {
                pathname: to,
            };
        }

        to = {
            state: null,
            search: '',
            ...to
        }
        console.log('to.pathname + to.search: ', to.pathname, to.search, to.state, this.props)
        if (push) {
            this.props.history.push(to.pathname + to.search, to.state);
            //this.context.history.push(to.pathname + to.search, to.state);

            //this.props.navigate(to.pathname + to.search, { state: to.state });
        }
        else {
            this.props.history.replace(to.pathname + to.search, to.state);
            //window.history.replace(to.pathname + to.search, to.state);
            //this.props.navigate(to.pathname + to.search, { state: to.state, replace: true });
        }
    }


    render() {
        return this.props.children;
    }
}

ContextWrap.propsTypes = {
    user: PropTypes.object,
    options: PropTypes.object,
    children: PropTypes.node,
    branch: PropTypes.object,
}

ContextWrap.childContextTypes = {
    user: PropTypes.object,
    request: PropTypes.object,
    options: PropTypes.object,
    redirect: PropTypes.func,
    locale: PropTypes.string,
};

export const Context = rdConnect(state => ({
    account: state.account,
    options: state.app.options
}))(ContextWrap);

export const connect = (component, mapStateToProp, actions, mapDispatchToProps) => {
    if (!component) {
        throw new Error("Component can not be null");
    }

    component.contextTypes = ContextWrap.childContextTypes;


    component.prototype.redirect = function (to, push) {
        if (this.context.redirect) {
            this.context.redirect(to, push);
        }
    }

    const make = actions ? rdConnect(mapStateToProp, dispatch => {
        if (typeof mapDispatchToProps == 'function') {
            return {
                actions: bindActionCreators(actions, dispatch),
                ...mapDispatchToProps(dispatch)
            }
        }
        else {
            return {
                actions: bindActionCreators(actions, dispatch)
            }
        }
    }, null, { withRef: true }) : rdConnect(mapStateToProp, mapDispatchToProps, null, { withRef: true });


    return make(component);
}
export default connect;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code to achieve navigation in your class component using withRouter:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import User from './user';
import request from './request';
import { connect as rdConnect, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

export class ContextWrap extends Component {
    static propTypes = {
        account: PropTypes.object,
        options: PropTypes.object,
        children: PropTypes.node,
        history: PropTypes.object.isRequired, 
    };

    getChildContext() {
        return {
            user: new User(this.props.account, this.redirect),
            request: request,
            options: this.props.options,
            redirect: this.redirect,
            locale: this.props.account.user ? this.props.account.user.metas.locale : null,
        };
    }

    redirect = (to, push) => {
        if (typeof to === 'string') {
            to = {
                pathname: to,
            };
        }

        to = {
            state: null,
            search: '',
            ...to
        };

        if (push) {
            this.props.history.push(to.pathname + to.search, to.state);
        } else {
            this.props.history.replace(to.pathname + to.search, to.state);
        }
    };

    render() {
        return this.props.children;
    }
}

// Here wrap your component with withRouter to inject history into the props
export default withRouter(
    rdConnect((state) => ({
        account: state.account,
        options: state.app.options
    }))(ContextWrap)
);
```